# converting a tcp client socket class from python2 to python3

Tags: python, sockets

I need to write a tcp client that runs in the background. I found an interesting class that does exactly what I need at this link: [Code sample - socket client thread](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/18/code-sample-socket-client-thread-in-python). I'd like to implement it in my project because I find it to be better than the examples in the standard library or the modules in [PyMOTW-3](https://pymotw.com/3/socket/tcp.html#choosing-an-address-for-listening). Problem is, it is written in Python2 and I keep getting an error with this method:

```
def _recv_n_bytes(self, n):
    data = ''
    while len(data) < n:
        chunk = self.socket.recv(n - len(data))
        print(chunk)
        if chunk == '':
            break
        data += chunk
    return data
```

During my research I've come to realize that Py2 and Py3 have a different behavior as to string interpretation. So I've tried basically any combination of decoding/encoding('UTF-8') the 'data' or the 'chunk', but somehow I end always end up at this line `chunk = self.socket.recv(n - len(data))`, where I get a generic 'MemoryError' (no further description)!

Does anyone know what's going on? Or alternatively, can anyone suggest me a ready-made class to set up a separate thread for a tcp client connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently playing with sockets myself an I ran into the same problem. What you should do is encode any data you are sending to the receiver and decode any data that you are receiving at the client.

so you should use something to the affect of `chunk = self.socket.recv(n - len(data)).decode()`

on the sending side you should encode as such: `socket.send(data.encode())`

Comment: Thanks Adam. I had tried encoding and decoding in various forms and types, but nothing worked. But now I've found what was causing the error... apparently the server I was contacting didn't send a standard Tcp header, thus the code was unable to correctly interpret it. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: sorry you had to debug that one!